# Pass Object of the selected value in angular 4 / 5

Tags: html, angular, select, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

I'm kinda new to angular and not sure if this is possible or not but -

I have an array of objects that I'm loading in my dropdown. This array only displays to the user the name of the Player and when the user selects the name, I wanted to pass the entire object of the selected name to the console or to the HTTP get method. However, right now I'm only getting the value that's inside the input box and not the entire object field as it originally was.

[object array as seen in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zejI.png)

And this is the code for the HTML side of the dropdown

```
 <form [formGroup]="userForm1" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit1()">
      <div class="form-group">
    <label class="field field_type1">
      <input list="browsers" type="text" class="field__input form-control" placeholder="e.g. Melnikov Stanislav" formControlName="name1">
      <datalist id="browsers">

      <span class="field__label-wrap">
        <span class="field__label">Search Player</span>
      </span>
            <option *ngFor="let pointers of atkpointer" [ngValue]="pointers">{{pointers.Name}}</option>
      </datalist>
    </label>

    <div>
      <button type="submit" class="button type3">
      Submit
      </button>
    </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Code on the component side:

```
onSubmit1(){
console.log(this.userForm1.value);
}
```

The output that I'm getting is:

[OUTPUT that I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vt8J6.png)

So what I really wanted in the output would be OVA, Balance, Crossing and things like that of the selected value rather than the name of the player. However we need to use the name to identify the player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your value in your submit function.

```
onSubmit1(){
  const payload: any = this.userForm1.value;
  payload.user = this.atkpointer.find(u => u.name === payload.name1);
  console.log(payload);
}
```

The values of your options should be simple strings, not full objects. I didn't comment on the validity of your HTML, but you definitely need to be aware of that.

**EDIT** To store only the object :

```
onSubmit1(){
  const user: any = this.atkpointer.find(u => u.name === this.userForm1.value.name1);
  console.log(user);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It took me a step closer but then the issue is that it will only try finding the value from the Name of the player, because " this.userFrom1.value is equal to the player name " .. how can I store the object in that place and search for the needed attribute.

Comment: I tried the edit. It seems to return me **undefined** . The code before the edit works the better. I think I'm making some issue in the HTML side. I have passed `[ngValue]="pointers"` but it stores the value of `{{pointers.Name}}` and that's why only the name is getting passed to the submit function.

Comment: Well if you have the name in the function, the edit should work. Something else must have changed. But anyways, you get the point of how you should do it, that's what matters most !

Comment: got the problem solved... it was the @angular/forms version that I was using, it was an old version and they didn't have that feature back then.